# Stackowerflow in recursion void

Tags: c#, parsing, recursion, stack-overflow

My function try parse text - find Vector3 modify it, if exist next Vector func call self again.
Its work fine for small text files, but with big text files all time stackoverflow. Parser try find text if not find - make exit, text file all times make small and small - its not "dead cycle". Error in rand places, usually a here  int pos = text.IndexOf(search); (Support module)

```
private void ParseText()
    {           

        if (isWorking)
        {
            isWorking = IsVectorReplace();
            ParseText();
            ProcessShow();
        }
        else
        {
            ParserWorkComplite();
        }
    }


    private bool IsVectorReplace()
    {
        //find index of substring start 
        int indexOfSubstringStart = fileContent.IndexOf(prefix);
        if (indexOfSubstringStart == -1) { return false; } //vector3 not find

        //find index of substring end            
        int nextCharIndx = indexOfSubstringStart;
        Char ch = fileContent[nextCharIndx];

        while (ch.ToString() != suffix)
        {
            ch = fileContent[nextCharIndx];                
            nextCharIndx++;
        }
        

        int startCutIndex = indexOfSubstringStart + prefix.Length;
        int endCutIndex = nextCharIndx - (indexOfSubstringStart + prefix.Length + 1);

        //search done. parse vector
        string vectorTextContent = fileContent.Substring(startCutIndex, endCutIndex);
        string oldVecText, newVecText;
        string vectorNewTextContent = "";
        parseVector3 = ConvertFromString(vectorTextContent);
        parseVector3 += shiftVector3;
        vectorNewTextContent = ConvertVect(parseVector3);        
        oldVecText = prefix + vectorTextContent + suffix;
        newVecText = prefix + vectorNewTextContent + suffix;
        string replaceText = ReplaceFirst(fileContent, oldVecText, newVecText);
        //Debug.WriteLine("VEC OLD " + vectorTextContent + " VEC NEW "+ vectorNewTextContent);

        int lastIndex = endCutIndex; // indexOfSubstringStart + newVecText.Length;

        //save and cut file 
        string savePartText = fileContent.Remove(lastIndex);
        partsOfFile.Add(savePartText);
        fileContent = fileContent.Remove(0, savePartText.Length);

        return true;
    }
```

Some supp modules:

```
        //find vec in string
    Vector3 ConvertFromString(string input)
    {
        if (input != null)
        {
            var vals = input.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).ToArray();
            
            if (vals.Length == 3)
            {
                NumberStyles style = System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Any;
                CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

                Single v1, v2, v3;
                if (Single.TryParse(vals[0], style, culture, out v1) && Single.TryParse(vals[1], style, culture, out v2) && Single.TryParse(vals[2], style, culture, out v3))
                    return new Vector3(v1, v2, v3);
                else
                    throw new ArgumentException();
            }
            else
                throw new ArgumentException();
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    //convert vect to text back
    private string ConvertVect(Vector3 v)
    {
        string data = "";
        string v0, v1, v2;
        v0 = v.X.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
        v1 = v.Y.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
        v2 = v.Z.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
        data = v0 + "," + v1 + "," + v2 + "";

        return data;
    }

    public string ReplaceFirst(string text, string search, string replace)
    {
        int pos = text.IndexOf(search);
        if (pos < 0)
        {
            return text;
        }
        return text.Substring(0, pos) + replace + text.Substring(pos + search.Length);
    }
```

Comment: Where does the StackOverflow occur? If the debgger stop at it, what is the call stack?

Comment: System.StackOverflowException" in System.Private.CoreLib.dll (int pos = text.IndexOf(search); in void ReplaceFirst) i think its after procent 20 or else for 2mb size text file size

Comment: And what's on the call stack?

Comment: `IsVectorReplace()` always returns `true`, so in `ParseText()`, `isWorking` always becomes `true`, so `ParseText()` calls itself indefinitely. Boom!

Comment: Its not always true and ofcouse its not indefinitely.  But yep, long long time true. To parse big files its few minuts. I know size of file and change true IsVectorReplace() to check procents of work, now without error, but need more tests.

Comment: Also i change recursion to while cycle and make it in async. Now work time was reduced from 10 mins+ for few mb files to 1 min. Maybe i add some more optimize later. Possible its still have this error in really big files, but i not need work with it. (i test parse with 2mb files)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you asked for, but based on the code you have provided, I would propose an entirely different approach using [`Regex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference)

Here is some code to use as a starting point
You'll need this using statement in your .cs file

```cs
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

```cs
//fileContent is assumed to be your original string containing Vector3 instances.
//prefix and suffix are assumed to be strings that mark the beginning and end of the Vector3 string respectively

string vectorRegex = $"(?<={ Regex.Escape(prefix) }).+?(?={ Regex.Escape(suffix) })";
string replacedContent = Regex.Replace(fileContent, vectorRegex, ModifyVector);
```

```cs
private static string ModifyVector(Match vectorMatch)
{
    //This is adapted from your code
    Vector3 parseVector3 = ConvertFromString(vectorMatch.Value);
    parseVector3 += shiftVector3;
    return ConvertVect(parseVector3);
}
```

The code above will do the following

1. Find all instances of text between `prefix` and `suffix` delimiters in `fileContent`
2. Invoke the `ModifyVector` function for each match
3. Replace the matched value with the output of the `ModifyVector` funtion